# CSS: css image resize to fit browser

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing

I am trying to make the images resize to fit the browser just like the background-image using

`max-width:100%;
height:auto;
max-height:100%;`

However, the images do not resize to fit the screen and i tried to adjust the size of the browser. The images would go everywhere. I want the images to stay on the same spot when ever resizing occur. Any ideas on what i might have missed?

```css
body{
  background: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/518169-backgrounds.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: 100%;

}
.boat2{
  width: 400px;
  position:absolute; bottom: 160px; left: 800px;z-index: 1;

}
.cabbage{
  width: 150px;
position:absolute; bottom: 290px; right: 290px;z-index: 1;
}
.sheep{
  width: 150px;
  position:absolute; bottom: 300px; right: 180px;z-index: 1;
}
.wolf{
  width: 300px;
  position:absolute; bottom: 270px; right: -80px;z-index: 1;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
 height:auto;
 max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>IQ River Crossing</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="image">
<img class="boat2"src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/christmas-background.jpg" alt="">
<img class="cabbage" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/christmas-background.jpg" alt="">
<img class="sheep" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/christmas-background.jpg" alt="">
<img class="wolf" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/christmas-background.jpg" alt="">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to have width and offsets applied to images.and it work according to that code.Your css seems to be totally wrong for the intention you mentioned or I misunderstood your question. Could you make this clear?

Comment: When u reduce the size of the browser, the pink leaf in the background image reduces its size as well. I want the green images to reduce in size just like that leaf.

Comment: Also, i want the green images to stay at the same spot when the browser is resizing. Let just say that the green images are on top of the pink leaf. I want the green images to remain exactly on top of the pink leaf (same position) when resizing the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try css reset

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

OR

you can refer https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Hope it helps